# How to filter data in Firebase and Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I use Ionic and Firebase in my project.

I need to filter users by gender and, due to there is too much data, I also have to implement pagination for ease of navigating through. 
I have been dealing with this problem for a long time, but still could not find a valid solution.

My database structure is:

[image: here]

My code is:

```
ref = this.afDB.database.ref('Users').orderByChild('Gender').equalTo('male').orderByChild('Id').startAt(lastItemKey).limitToFirst(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `orderBy...()` multiple times on the same query. See [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

But you can use the two-parameter version of `equalTo()` to accomplish what you want:

```
db.ref('Users').orderByChild('Gender').equalTo('male', lastItemKey).limitToFirst(10)
```

The `lastItemKey` in this snippet is used when there are multiple child nodes with `Gender` equal to `male` to determine at which one to start.